# Difficulty communicating over serial ports in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, serial-port

I have success writing code in Windows and performing serial port communication.  But not in Linux so far.

Here is the code I wrote:
I have used `Picocom` to verify that I can communicate over the serial ports via my (USB to NULL Modem to USB) cable.

Setting the code to None blocking yields "`errno: 11    Resource temporarily unavailable`" on both client and server."

When I set to Blocking, it hangs in code at the Read File method.  If I comment that line out it runs... but not getting data.

---

```
Server sends packets continuous. 
Client receives packets continuous. 

Problem seems to be bytes aren't received at the client.  They are sent, however at the server.

CLIENT:

RECV(1611912):  NumChars: 0    String: 
RECV(1611913):  NumChars: 0    String: 
RECV(1611918):  NumChars: 0    String: 
RECV(1611919):  NumChars: 0    String: 
RECV(1611920):  NumChars: 0    String:
```

---

```
SERVER:

SENT(106775):  NumChars: 10    String: 0123456789
SENT(106776):  NumChars: 10    String: 0123456789
SENT(106777):  NumChars: 10    String: 0123456789
SENT(106778):  NumChars: 10    String: 0123456789
SENT(106779):  NumChars: 10    String: 0123456789
```

---

```
to run: 
g++ -o sp serialport.cpp

client:  ./sp /dev/ttyS0 c
server:  ./sp /dev/ttyS4 s


#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h> 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>
 
 class C_SerialPort
 {
  private:
    int  giFD;
    char gpcDevice[100] = {0};

  public:
  
    //------------------------------------------------
    //
    //------------------------------------------------
    int GetError(char* pcMessage = (char*)"")
    {
      char pcError[100] = {0};
      sprintf(pcError, "  (%s):   errno: %d    %s\n", pcMessage, errno, strerror(errno));

      if(errno > 0)
      {
        printf("%s", pcError);
      }

      return errno;
    }


    //------------------------------------------------
    //
    //------------------------------------------------
    int Connect() 
    {
      return Connect((char*)"/dev/ttyS0");
      //return Connect((char*)"/dev/ttyUSB0");
    }
    

    //------------------------------------------------
    //
    //------------------------------------------------
    int Connect(char *pcDevice) 
    {
      strcpy(gpcDevice, pcDevice);

      struct termios s_TA;
      
      // Open the serial port
      giFD = open(gpcDevice, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY | O_FSYNC );
      if(giFD < 0)
      {
        printf("open_port: Unable to open %s\n%s", gpcDevice, strerror(errno));
        printf("EXITING...\n");
        return 1;
      }
      else
      {
        printf("Connect Device: %s\n", gpcDevice);
      }


      // get attributes
      if(tcgetattr(giFD, &s_TA) != 0) 
      {
        GetError((char*)"tcgetattr");
        printf("EXITING...\n");
        return 1;
      }



      // clear terminalAttributes data
      //memset(&s_TA, 0, sizeof(struct termios));
      
      if(0)
      {
        // 57600 bauds; 8 bits per word; Ignore modem control lines; Enable receiver.
        s_TA.c_cflag = B57600 | CS8 | CLOCAL | CREAD;
        
        // Ignore framing errors and parity errors.
        s_TA.c_iflag = IGNPAR |  ONLCR;
        
        //Enable implementation-defined output processing.
        s_TA.c_oflag = OPOST;
        
        // min time; min bytes to read
        s_TA.c_cc[VTIME] = 1;
        s_TA.c_cc[VMIN] = 1;// none zero blocks
      }
      else
      {

        cfsetospeed(&s_TA, B9600);
        cfsetispeed(&s_TA, B9600);

        s_TA.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD);    /* ignore modem controls */
        s_TA.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
        s_TA.c_cflag |= CS8;         /* 8-bit characters */
        s_TA.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;     /* no parity bit */
        s_TA.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;     /* only need 1 stop bit */
        s_TA.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS;    /* no hardware flowcontrol */

        /* setup for non-canonical mode */
        s_TA.c_iflag &= ~(IGNBRK | BRKINT | PARMRK | ISTRIP | INLCR | IGNCR | ICRNL | IXON);
        s_TA.c_lflag &= ~(ECHO | ECHONL | ICANON | ISIG | IEXTEN);
        s_TA.c_oflag &= ~OPOST;


        /* fetch bytes as they become available */
        s_TA.c_cc[VMIN] = 1;  // 0   1
        s_TA.c_cc[VTIME] = 1; // 0   1
      }

      //int iVal = fcntl(giFD, F_SETFL, 0); // set blocking?
      //printf("file status = 0x%x\n", iVal);
      //GetError((char*)"fcntl");

      // Set the port to our state
      if (tcsetattr(giFD, TCSANOW, &s_TA) != 0) 
      {
        GetError((char*)"tcsetattr");
        printf("EXITING...\n");
        return 1;
      }

      // flushes data written but not transmitted.
      // flushes data received but not read.
      tcflush(giFD, TCOFLUSH);
      tcflush(giFD, TCIFLUSH);
      

      printf("CONNECTION OK\n");

      //return giFD;
      return 0;
    }
    

    //------------------------------------------------
    //
    //------------------------------------------------
    void Disconnect(void)
    {
      close(giFD);
      printf("nPort 1 has been CLOSED and %d is the file descriptionn", giFD);

      GetError((char*)"Disconnect");
    }
    

    //------------------------------------------------
    //
    //------------------------------------------------
    int SendArray(unsigned char *buffer, int len) 
    {
      int n = write(giFD, buffer, len);

      // error catch
      if(n < 0)
        GetError((char*)"write");

      return n;
    }
    

    //------------------------------------------------
    //
    //------------------------------------------------
    int GetArray (unsigned char *buffer, int len)
    {
      int n = 0;

      int len2 = BytesToRead();
       n = read(giFD, buffer, len2); // this line is an issue? with settings?

      // error catch
      //if(n < 0)
       // GetError((char*)"read");

      return n;
    }
    

    //------------------------------------------------
    //
    //------------------------------------------------
    void Clear()
    {
      tcflush(giFD, TCIFLUSH);
      tcflush(giFD, TCOFLUSH);
    }
    

    //------------------------------------------------
    //
    //------------------------------------------------
    int BytesToRead()
    {
      int iBytes = 0;
      ioctl(giFD, FIONREAD, &iBytes);
      
      //printf("Byte2Read: %d\n", iBytes);
      // error catch
      GetError((char*)"BytesToRead");

      return iBytes;
    }
 };



//------------------------------------------------
//
//------------------------------------------------
 int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
 {
  // device
  char *pcDevice = (char*)argv[1];
  printf("init:device:%s\n", pcDevice);

  // connection type
  char cConnType = argv[2][0];
  printf("ConnectionType:%c\n", cConnType);

  // instantiate SerialPort
  C_SerialPort c_SP;

  // connect
  int iReturn = c_SP.Connect(pcDevice);
  if(iReturn != 0)
  {
    printf("EXITING...\n");
    return 1;
  }

  // clear buffer
  c_SP.Clear();
  printf("clear\n");

  printf("prior...\n");

  // main loop
  while(1)
  {
    int iSleep_ms = 200;
    usleep(iSleep_ms);

    char pcArray[100] = {0};
    int iNumChars = 0;

  
    if(cConnType == 's')
    {
      static long lCount = 0;
      
      // Send
      strcpy(pcArray, "0123456789");
      iNumChars = c_SP.SendArray((unsigned char*)pcArray, 10);
        
      if(iNumChars > 0)
      {
        printf("SENT(%ld):  NumChars: %d    String: %s\n", lCount, iNumChars, pcArray);
      }

      lCount++;
    }


    
    if(cConnType == 'c')
    {
      static long lCount = 0;

      // Receive
      iNumChars = c_SP.GetArray((unsigned char*)pcArray, sizeof(pcArray));

      if(iNumChars > 0)
      {
        printf("RECV(%ld):  NumChars: %d    String: %s\n", lCount, iNumChars, pcArray);
      }
      else
      {
        //printf("RECV:  NumChars: %d    String: %s\n", iNumChars, pcArray);
      }

      lCount++;
    }

  }

  c_SP.Disconnect();

  return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Problem seems to be bytes aren't received at the client.  They are sent, however at the server.

Comment: How much data do you want `GetArray` to retrieve on each call?

Comment: It gets what is in the buffer and is supposed to return that count.

Comment: And if the buffer is empty?

Comment: showed results above

Comment: Obtaining the terminal configuration using **tcgetattr()** and then obliterating that data with a **memset()** is illogical and therefore incorrect.  See [Setting Terminal Modes Properly](http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/libc/libc_12.html#SEC237)

Answer (score 1):

You have four major bugs:

1. Your `GetArray` function ignores the return value of `BytesToRead`. It should read the lesser of the buffer size or the number of bytes available.
2. Your code has no ability to sanely handle the case where `BytesToRead` returns zero.
3. You ignore the return value of `GetArray`. When you print `pcArray`, you do not tell `printf` how many characters to output. So how is it supposed to know what to print?
4. You overwrite the returned values from `tcgetattr` by calling `memset`.

Comment: I removed memset on tcgetattr.
Good catch on the number of bytes to read.   But the NumberOfBytes2Read is always 0... still.

Comment: @jdl You need to do something sane in that case. What do you want to do if there are no bytes to read? (That's bug number 2.)

Comment: I solved the problem... thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the serial port to communicate through.

The `/dev/ttyS0` and `/dev/ttyS4` are the serial ports after the USB in the NULL modem cable hook up. But to communicate I had to use `/dev/ttyUSB0`  and   `/dev/ttyUSB1`